# Objective C - Change all attributes in NSAttributedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring

```
[attributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:range options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:
     ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

         NSMutableDictionary *mutableAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
         [mutableAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"NSUnderline"];
         attributes = mutableAttributes;

     }];
```

I am trying to loop through all attributed and add NSUnderline to them. when debugging it seems like NSUnderline is added to the dictionary, but when i loop for the second time they are removed.
Am I doing anything wrong while updating NSDictionaries?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782450/objective-c-change-all-attributes-in-nsattributedstring/6782514#6782514) does a good job of explaining why it doesn't work. To make it work, you need to tell the attributed string to use these new attributes.

```
[attributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:range options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:
     ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

         NSMutableDictionary *mutableAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
         [mutableAttributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"NSUnderline"];
         [attributedString setAttributes:mutableAttributes range:range];

 }];
```

Changing the attributes of an attributed string requires that it is a NSMutableAttributedString.

There is also an easier way to do this. NSMutableAttributedString defines the `addAttribute:value:range:` method, which sets the value of a specific attribute over the specified range, without changing other attributes. You can replace your code with a simple call to this method (still requiring a mutable string).

```
[attributedString addAttribute:@"NSUnderline" value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:(NSRange){0,[attributedString length]}];
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my other question about attributedStrings? thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783754/objective-c-nsattributedstring-extend-attributes

Comment: Would `addAttribute:value:range:` overwrite an existing value with the same key over the same range?  Or would it just not add the attribute at all?

Comment: @chown The documentation doesn't say, so I tested it and confirm that it overwrites the existing value.

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks a lot for figuring that out for me!  (I would have tested myself but my MacBookPro is dead at the moment).

Answer (score 5):

You're modifying a local copy of the dictionary; the attributed string does not have any way to see the change.

Pointers in C are passed by value (and thus what they point to is passed by reference.) So when you assign a new value to `attributes`, the code that called the block has no idea you changed it. The change does not propagate outside of the block's scope.