# Getting the attribute dictionaries from a NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c

How can I obtain the attributes of an NSAttributedString?

I thought using `enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)` and then saving every attributes in a NSMutableDictionaries but I'd like to know if exists a better way.

EDIT------ 
My problem is that I have a `NSAttributedString` and i want to use this function on its attributes...

```
CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter,range, __ATTRIBUTES__, size , NULL);
```

Comment: doest this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782450/objective-c-change-all-attributes-in-nsattributedstring

Comment: Do you really need to supply attributes to that function? If you created the framesetter with the attributed string in question, it should already know how to handle them, so you should be able to pass in NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSDictionary *attributesFromString = [string attributesAtIndex:0 longestEffectiveRange:nil inRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UITextView *t = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[t setAttributedText:a];
t.typingAttributtes
```